# Access to object in class - thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have classes like this:

```
public class Poetry {

    private String title;
    private Author author;

    // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class Author {

    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And this is the way I refer to `title`:

```
th:field="${poetry.title}"
```

But how can I refer to `poetry.author`? I get this exception:

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "poetry.author"
```

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div th:each="poetry : ${poetries}">
    <p th:text="${poetry.title}"></p>
    <p th:text="${poetry.content}"></p>
    <p th:text="${poetry.author}"></p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: add your code of a template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try accessing a field within the author, something like `${poetry.author.name}`

Comment: I get Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "poetry.author.name" (news:18) and logs: https://pastebin.com/6N9Ac9Qw

Comment: The thing that strikes me is `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` - meaning your author isn't initialized (it's set to lazy load). Either properly initialize the author, or set it to `@Eager`